# Why is ASP.NET Core Identity 2.0 Authorize filter causing me to get a 404?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I have a controller that I want to restrict only to a specific role, let's say `admin`. After setting a user with the `admin` role, I can validate that he's on that role using the `IsInRoleAsync` method (which returns true). When setting the attribute with `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` I get a 404 with that very same user . I'm using bearer tokens (I don't think that is relevant but anyway) and here's what I've done to try debugging:

Controller w/o `[Authorize]` : the resource is returned. [OK]

Controller with `[Authorize]` : the resource is returned *only* when I use the `Authentication: Bearer [access token]` [OK]

Controller with `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` : even after logging in with the user that has the role set, I get the 404 [NOK]

I don't know if I'm missing some configuration, but here's my ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        options.UseOpenIddict();
    });
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddOpenIddict(opt =>
    {
        opt.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        opt.AddMvcBinders();
        opt.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/token");
        opt.AllowPasswordFlow();
        opt.DisableHttpsRequirement(); //for dev only!
        opt.UseJsonWebTokens();
        opt.AddEphemeralSigningKey();
        opt.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
        opt.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OAuthValidationConstants.Schemes.Bearer;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.Authority = "http://localhost:44337/";
           options.Audience = "resource_server";
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               NameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
               RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role
           };                   
       });
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        // Add application services.
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType= OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
    });

    services.AddSingleton(typeof(RoleManager<ApplicationUser>));
    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely get a 404 response because Identity - which is automatically configured as the default authentication, sign-in/sign-out and challenge/forbidden scheme by `services.AddIdentity()` - tries to redirect you to the "access denied page" (`Account/AccessDenied` by default), that probably doesn't exist in your application.

Try to override the default challenge/forbidden scheme to see if it fixes your issue:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // ...
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

---

To fix your second issue, make sure the JWT claims mapping feature is disabled. If it's not, the JWT handler will "convert" all your `role` claims to `ClaimTypes.Role`, which won't work as you configured it to use `role` as the role claim used by `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole(...)` (`RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role`).

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    // ...
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
    {
        // Disable the built-in JWT claims mapping feature.
        InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, that explains and solves the 404, yet, why am I not able to access the content since my user has the required role? Now i get a 403

Comment: @DanielS. answer updated with a fix for your second issue.

Comment: As you stated, my problem was that I had no "Roles" on my token, as I thought that identity would check on the `AspNetUserRoles` if the user had that role assigned. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is to check claims, not roles. Add an `AuthorizeAttribute` such as:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminOnly")]
```

And then configure a policy that requires a claim:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
                      policy.RequireClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role, "Admin"));
});
```

Or, for debugging purposes or more advanced validation, you could have:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
                      policy.RequireAssertion(ctx =>
   {
       //do your checks
       return true;
   }));
});
```

Comment: I'll try that, although on [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles) it doesn't seem to be need. I mean, sounds like different things.

Comment: Roles are somewhat old school, now it's all about claims.

Comment: Even with that policy thing, it returns a 404

Comment: To debug, you can add instead of a RequireClaim a RequireAssertion. From there you get the request context and you can return either true or false.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Sorry I had to change subject for a while. I was trying to print the ctx.User.Identity but I wasn't being able to see it on the logs. Any way to inject the logger on the ConfigureServices method?