# Role based authorization in asp core 2 with jwt tokens and identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

I have tried some authorization examples in asp core 2 wiht jwt tokens and asp core identity. I have followed this code https://github.com/SunilAnthony/SimpleSecureAPI and it works fine.

The problem is role based authorization. I tried something like this: 
http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-roles-with-the-jwt-middleware/

and the result is strange. 
My controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = User.Claims; // contains claim with Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" and Value = "Administrator"
    bool role = User.IsInRole("Administrator"); // true
    bool claim = User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"); // true

    return Ok(claims);
}
```

When I call this endpoint just with attribute `[Authorize]` and check role / claims in code for current user it seems good (both checks are true), but when I have changed my authorization attribute to `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` it does not work -> **when I call this endpoint with this attribute I will receive 404**. I don't know where is the problem. My startup class is completely same as in the git link above and I have just added list of string role names in the payload of access_token within then "roles" array:

It is hardcoded but I have changed my login method just for test like this:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([FromBody] Credentials Credentials)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Credentials.Email, Credentials.Password, false, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Credentials.Email);

            List<string> roles = new List<string>();
            roles.Add("Administrator");

            return new JsonResult(new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "access_token", GetAccessToken(Credentials.Email, roles) },
                    { "username", user.Email },
                    { "expired_on", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_tokenLength) },
                    { "id_token", GetIdToken(user) }
                });
        }
        return new JsonResult("Unable to sign in") { StatusCode = 401 };
    }
    return new JsonResult("Unable to sign in") { StatusCode = 401 };
}
```

And the `GetAccessTokenMethod`:

```
private string GetAccessToken(string Email, List<string> roles)
{
  var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    { "sub", Email },
    { "email", Email },
    { "roles", roles },
  };
  return GetToken(payload);
}
```

Where is the problem with the `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` attribute?

Comment: Have you checked whether the endpoint is actually returning a redirect? It seems like your authorization check is failing and then perhaps trying to redirect you to a missing login page.

Comment: Problem is not the 404 (yes, I have no login page), but the situation, that I have the user which has role/claim "Administrator" and I don't know how to configure role based authorization to work with attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]. Currently the same user gets 404 even he has this role.The similar problem was described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915929/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-authorize-filter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the claim's type:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role
```

Somehow, the `[Authorize]` attribute fails to work when used with `Roles` value. 
So this `[Authorize(Roles = "Administartor")]` doesn't work.
You have to map the claim type to only `role` by applying transformation on `Startup` class.

If you have an `Owin` based project:

```
app.UseClaimsTransformation(incoming =>
            {
                // either add claims to incoming, or create new principal
                var appPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(incoming);
                if (appPrincipal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"))
                {
                    var value = appPrincipal.Claims.First(x =>
                        x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role").Value;

                    incoming.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("role", value));
                }                

                return Task.FromResult(appPrincipal);
            });
```