# ASP.NET Authorize Filter Denies Access for User in Specified Role

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-authorization

In my ASP.NET Core 2.0 Application, I am stuck with an issue an Admin logged in User cannot access controller I used the Authorize Filter on `[Authorize(Policy="AdminAlone")]`.

I confirmed that the user is in the "Administrators" role and added the policy in `startup.cs` but it redirects to an AccessDenied view when I try to access the controller.

I saw a similar problem on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915929/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-authorize-filter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but the solution didn't help me

**Startup Class in MVC Client - ConfigureServices**

```cs
services.AddMvc();
services.AddSession();

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminAlone", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrators"));
});

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.ClientId = "mvcWeb";
    options.ClientSecret = "spring12345";
    options.ResponseType = OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeIdToken;

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.Scope.Add("NuB.HospitalSearch");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
});
```

**Web API ConfigureServices**

```cs
var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
{
    InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
};

services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(option =>
{
   option.Audience = "NuB.HospitalSearch";
   option.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
   option.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
   option.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
   option.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(jwtSecurityTokenHandler);
   option.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
   {
       ValidateAudience = true,
       ValidAudience = "NuB.HospitalSearch",
       ValidateIssuer = true
   };
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference (or not) but perhaps this alternative might work: options.AddPolicy("AdminAlone", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrators"));

Comment: @Vlince thanks for your response. I tried your solution but didn't work. Please see the comment of Giorgos answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following. Inside your [AddOpenIdConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.openidconnectextensions.addopenidconnect?view=aspnetcore-2.0) configuration add

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
   NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
   RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
};
```

In fact, this property defines the types and definitions required for validating a token. Please refer to [this](https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/) post from **Dominick Baier** for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi. I tried your solution and read the post from Dominick Baier. (Thanks for the post. I got to know more about the Microsoft implementation of oidc) But unfortunately, it didn't work. I even tried out @Vlince's idea even before I realized he posted it. Still, nothing! However, I noticed when I used `JwtClaimTypes.Role` it didn't work. But when I tried another claim `JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName` for instance and it worked. So it seems that the `JwtClaimTypes.Role` is being ignored somehow. I wonder why.

Comment: Are you sure the roles are in the JWT? paste it into https://jwt.io/ and see if the claims are there. If, for example, you're using ADFS it leaves roles out by default because there can be so many.